# Regular expression for a password containing at least 2 uppercase letters, 2 lowercase letters, 2 symbols, and 2 numbers in any sequence

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is not working in JavaScript password validation when I am using it with RegEx():

```
(?=(.*\\d){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*?]){2,})(?!.*[\\s])^.*
```

Comment: Maybe better don't use regex for this purpose? I would write it on JS.

Comment: it is not working even in ng-pattern @artamonovdev

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:
The regex that I've used is:

1) (?=(.*\d){2}) --> atleast 2 digits

2) (?=(.*[a-z]){2}) --> atleast 2 lower case chars
3) (?=(.*[A-Z]){2}) --> atleast 2 upper case chars

4) (?=(.*[!@#$%]){2}) --> atleast 2 special chars, can be any one                             of !, @, #, $, %

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.password = '';

    // (?=(.*\d){2}) --> atleast 2 digits
    // (?=(.*[a-z]){2}) --> atleast 2 lower case chars
    // (?=(.*[A-Z]){2}) --> atleast 2 upper case chars
    // (?=(.*[!@#$%]){2}) --> atleast 2 special chars, can be any one of !, @, #, $, %
    $scope.pattern = /(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(.*[!@#$%]){2})/;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <form name="myForm">
    <label>Enter password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" ng-pattern="pattern">
    <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="myForm.password.$error.pattern">Password is not valid, doesn't match the provided pattern.</span>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: it is working @Gaurav. I don't have to use RegEx() function.You saved my day.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.password = '';

    // (?=(.*\d){2}) --> atleast 2 digits
    // (?=(.*[a-z]){2}) --> atleast 2 lower case chars
    // (?=(.*[A-Z]){2}) --> atleast 2 upper case chars
    // (?=(.*[!@#$%]){2}) --> atleast 2 special chars, can be any one of !, @, #, $, %
    $scope.pattern = /(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[a-z]){2})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(.*[!@#$%]){2})/;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <form name="myForm">
    <label>Enter password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" ng-pattern="pattern">
    <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-show="myForm.password.$error.pattern">Password is not valid, doesn't match the provided pattern.</span>
  </form>

</div>
```